# Can getIntent() in OnCreate of Activity get the Extra data pass by PendingIntent from AlarmManager for self Activity restart?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

the code to start alarmManager after 10 sec

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SelfUpdateByScanQrCodeEventActivity.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("startInstallUpdateApk",true);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    SelfUpdateByScanQrCodeEventActivity.getContext().getApplicationContext(), createRestartAgentAlarmManagerRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) SelfUpdateByScanQrCodeEventActivity.getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND,delaySecTimeToRestartAgent);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
                
            }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
               
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                
            }
```

the cod of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preparation);
        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        boolean startInstallUpdateApk = extras.getBoolean("startInstallUpdateApk");
}
}
```

Can I get the key,startInstallUpdateApk , onCreate after MainActivity called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question

> Can I get the key,"startInstallUpdateApk" , `onCreate` after `MainActivity` called?

is "yes". However...

Your code is calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` when it should be calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. When the alarm triggers nothing will happen now because an `Activity Intent` and a broadcast `Intent` are 2 completely different things.

Comment: It seems that I need to check how to use the PendingIntent getXXX methods. Thank you.